# jme3 - UV map misplaced on model exported from Blender

Tags: java, 3d, blender, jmonkeyengine, uv-mapping

I created a [simple model of a barrel (.zip)](http://bit.ly/1iqnAhX) in Blender 2.69. Then I created a UV map in Blender and made a UV mapped texture out of it (its in the archive, too). Then I imported my texture in Blender, now the mapping matches:

[image: The mapping]

In Blender the model looks fine so far:

[image: Model in Blender]

By using the Ogre exporter plugin that I installed via the jmonkeyengine SDK, I exported the model. The result of this is my OgreXML format file of the barrel (I did not export material).

Now, I tried to add the barrel to my world like this:

```
this.barrel = this.assetManager.loadModel("models/barrel/Barrel.mesh.xml");

Material barrelMat = new Material(this.assetManager,
        "Common/MatDefs/Light/Lighting.j3md");
barrelMat.setTexture("DiffuseMap",
        this.assetManager.loadTexture("models/barrel/Barrel.jpg"));
barrelMat.setBoolean("UseMaterialColors", true);
barrelMat.setColor("Diffuse", ColorRGBA.White);
barrelMat.setColor("Specular", new ColorRGBA(0.3f, 0.1f, 0, 1));
barrelMat.setFloat("Shininess", 4f);
this.barrel.setMaterial(barrelMat);

this.rootNode.attachChild(this.barrel);
```

The result is this:

[image: The failed barrel image]

Is there something else I have to consider when setting the texture for my UV mapped model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often when transferring models from Blender to something like JME, the textures will be upside down.  Where you load the texture:

```
barrelMat.setTexture(“DiffuseMap”, 
                     assetManager.loadTexture(“models/barrel/Barrel.jpg”));
```

Instead use the TextureKey form of the loadTexture() method and pass yFlip false since true is the default.

```
assetManager.loadTexture(new TextureKey(“models/barrel/Barrel.jpg”, false));
```

That should fix your issue.

References:

loadTexture() : http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/javadoc/com/jme3/asset/AssetManager.html#loadTexture(com.jme3.asset.TextureKey)

TextureKey : http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/javadoc/com/jme3/asset/TextureKey.html#TextureKey(java.lang.String,%20boolean)

Comment: The links are dead.